# Routing to a file path with AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

All,

I'm sure there's a very simple solution that I'm missing but I've given up looking!

I'm using Route 53 on AWS with elastic beanstalk. At the moment I've got a CNAME to route to my elastic beanstalk instance which is working fine, but I'm trying to get another one with a different subdomain linking to another path but don't seem to be having any success.

For example:

CNAME 1: `www.example.com` Routing to `mysite.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`

CNAME 2: `news.example.com` Routing to `mysite.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/news`

I've tried testing the second one, and noted that the response returned as \057 in place of the forward slash, not sure if that's part of the reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Route53 is a DNS service. DNS is only used for the domain name portion of the request. Route53 can not route to a specific path. You would need to configure your Apache or Nginx server on your Elastic Beanstalk instance to route requests for the 2nd domain name to that specific path.